# UITextField - detect input on built-in iPhone keyboard?

Tags: iphone, ios, keyboard, uitextfield

[UITextFieldVariable becomeFirstResponder]; is bringing the keyboard on to the screen.

How can I detect when a user types in a letter on the keyboard?
I'd like to know each time a key has been pressed.

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `NSNotificationCenter` and take a look at the `UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification`.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
          selector:@selector(textFieldChanged)
              name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification
            object:textField];
```

Now implement a function `-(void)textFieldChanged;` and each time this function gets called compare the new text in the `UITextField` with the old text. Whatever has changed is the button that was pressed.

Do something similar for `UITextFieldTextDidBeginEditingNotification` and `UITextFieldTextDidEndEditingNotification` to ensure that buttons were pressed even though no text was typed (like pressing backslash).

Comment: Awesome!  I just had to remove the colon after the @selector function name for this to work  @selector(textFieldChanged)

Comment: Terrible answer: "Do something similar for UITextFieldTextDidBeginEditingNotification and UITextFieldTextDidEndEditingNotification to ensure that buttons were pressed even though no text was typed (like pressing backslash)." This is factually untrue!

Comment: Actually if you want to delete see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13942968/274179

Answer (score 2):

Give your text field(s) a delegate. The delegate's `-textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` method will be called whenever the user changes the text, including by typing characters on the keyboard.

Comment: This method wont be called if the text field is empty and the user pressed backslash.

Comment: Dimme, this still won't work when the text is empty and backslash is pressed. How is your solution with UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification different to the delegate's textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString? It's not, they both do the same thing! This doesn't work to intercept every backspace press